# Separate a name into first and last name using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
name                      birth
John Henry Smith           1980
Hannah Gonzalez            1900
Michael Thomas Ford        1950
Michelle Lee               1984
```

And I want to create two new columns, "middle" and "last" for the middle and last names of each person, respectively. People who have no middle name should have None in that data frame.

This would be my ideal result:

```
name       middle    last       birth
John       Henry     Smith       1980
Hannah     None      Gonzalez    1900
Michael    Thomas    Ford        1950
Michelle   None      Lee         1984
```

I have tried different approaches, such as this:

```
df['middle'] = df['name'].map(lambda x: x.split(" ")[1] if x.count(" ")== 2 else None)
df['last'] = df['name'].map(lambda x: x.split(" ")[1] if x.count(" ")== 1 else x.split(" ")[2])
```

I even made some functions that try to do the same thing more carefully, but I always get the same error: "List Index out of range". This is weird because if I go about printing df.iloc[i,0].split(" ") for i in range(len(df)), I do get lists with length 2 or length 3 only.

I also printed x.count(" ") for all x in the "name" column and I always got either 1 or 2 as a result. There are no single names.

This is my first question so thank you so much!

Comment: your code seems fine (didn't run it) but `x: x.split(" ")[1]` can cause an issue. if you have a name without any spaces, you will get an index error because there is no `1th` element in the list. filter out any data without spaces and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with **`expand = True`**.

```
df2 = (df['name'].str
                 .split(' ',expand = True)
                 .rename(columns = {0:'name',1:'middle',2:'last'}))

new_df = df2.assign(middle = df2['middle'].where(df2['last'].notnull()),
                    last = df2['last'].fillna(df2['middle']),
                    birth = df['birth'])
print(new_df)
       name  middle      last  birth
0      John   Henry     Smith   1980
1    Hannah     NaN  Gonzalez   1900
2   Michael  Thomas      Ford   1950
3  Michelle     NaN       Lee   1984
```

Comment: When I pass this table to an SQL database, will the Nan values be interpreted as NULL? That's what I am looking for.

Comment: I think so, if you have problems, you can try: `new_df = new_df.where(new_df.notnull(),None)`, at the end